# How can I make a data URL from a local file with Python?

Tags: python

I can read in a local file like so, but how can I now get the local file represented as a data url?  I can't see any method for doing so.

This is a data url:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

```
import urllib.request
import random
import os

filename = urllib.request.pathname2url(random.choice(os.listdir('./sampledocuments')))
print(filename)

r = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///Users/myusername/sampledocuments/' + filename)


print(r)
print(r.info)
print(r.geturl)
print(dir(r))
```

Comment: I think you need to run a server like `python -m http.server`

Comment: I've updated to include a link to explain what a data url is.

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this? Could you use the standard `open` call in Python instead of `file:///` URLs to open local files - (e.g. `open('/Users/myusername/sampledocuments/...')`?

Comment: Let me quote the page you linked: "Data URLs, URLs prefixed with the `data:` scheme,[…]". That's where you have to start.

Comment: @nneonneo I need to do it because I want to send a data url somewhere.  I thought urllib would be th right tool.  urllib is able to read data urls - I thought it would also be able to generate data urls.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward: given `mimetype` and `data`,

```
import base64
...
f"data:{mimetype or ''};base64,{base64.b64encode(data).decode()}"
```

To get the data, you can modify your code as follows:

```
filename = random.choice(os.listdir('./sampledocuments'))
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Set the `mimetype` if you know what it is, but it will work even if it's `None` (it just may not do what you want).

Comment: Works well thanks although it's a pity Python isn't able to represent a file loaded via urllib as a data url.

Comment: Doesn't matter how you load it, as long as you have contents in `data` the above code will work.